# porque mi br no funciona con el document.write

Tags: javascript

Tengo este pequeño código que lleva la sumatoria de unos números, pero a la hora de desplegarlos con el document.write, no me los despliega en lista.
soy nueva en js si alguien me puede orientar porfavor.

```js
alert("Vamos a Contar");
 let result = '';
       let i = 0;
       let cont = 0;

   do {
   <!--alert("Iniciamos");-->
       i = i + cont;
       result = result + i;
       cont = cont +1
 <!--alert(cont);-->
 <!--alert (result);-->
      } while (i <=90);

document.write(result + "<br>");
```

Comment: Cual sería el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 4):

Tu elemento `<br>` se está escribiendo una única vez ya fuera del bucle `while`. Si lo que quieres es que el resultado contenga tantos elementos `<br>`como iteraciones se realicen, haz de ajustar la linea que asigna el valor a la variable `result` de las siguiente forma:

```js
result = result + i + '<br>';
```

o bien podrías usar la forma compacta:

```js
result += i + '<br>';
```

```js
let result = '';
let i = 0;
let cont = 0;
do {
  i = i + cont;
  result += i + '<br>';
  cont++;
} while (i <=90);

document.write(result);
```

Recuerda que en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) el operador `+`, cuando se usa con cadenas de texto, no es el operador de `suma` sino que es el operador de `concatenación`. El motor de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) hará el *cast* adecuado del valor de `i` que es numérico, a su representación de cadena, para poder concatenar el elemento `<br>`.